# Powershell export CSV looks weird

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an issue with my CSV export to Excel with powershell. When I import it looks like pretty bad and I can't find any information that helps me to solve it.
Here I attach an image of the import and the code. I see other CSV imports and it looks normal with its categories spaced by rows in Excel, but I don't know how to do it.

[Image of my workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QfmG.png)

```
 $Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "*Server*"} -Properties OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
   Foreach($computer in $computers){
if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
  {write-host "cannot reach $computer offline" -f red}
   else {
$outtbl = @()
Try{
$sr=Get-WmiObject win32_bios -ComputerName $Computer  -ErrorAction Stop 
$Xr=Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Stop   
$ld=get-adcomputer $computer -properties Name,Lastlogondate,operatingsystem,ipv4Address,enabled,description,DistinguishedName -ErrorAction Stop
$r="{0} GB" -f ((Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $computer |Measure-Object Capacity  -Sum).Sum / 1GB)
$x = gwmi win32_computersystem -ComputerName $computer |select @{Name = "Type";Expression = {if (($_.pcsystemtype -eq '2')  ) 

{'Laptop'} Else {'Desktop Or Other something else'}}},Manufacturer,@{Name = "Model";Expression = {if (($_.model -eq "$null")  ) {'Virtual'} Else {$_.model}}},username -ErrorAction Stop
$t= New-Object PSObject -Property @{
 serialnumber = $sr.serialnumber
 computername = $ld.name
 Ipaddress=$ld.ipv4Address
 Enabled=$ld.Enabled
 Description=$ld.description
 Ou=$ld.DistinguishedName.split(',')[1].split('=')[1] 
 Type = $x.type
 Manufacturer=$x.Manufacturer
 Model=$x.Model
 Ram=$R
 ProcessorName=($xr.name | Out-String).Trim()
 NumberOfCores=($xr.NumberOfCores | Out-String).Trim()
 NumberOfLogicalProcessors=($xr.NumberOfLogicalProcessors | Out-String).Trim()
 Addresswidth=($xr.Addresswidth | Out-String).Trim()
 Operatingsystem=$ld.operatingsystem
 Lastlogondate=$ld.lastlogondate
 LoggedinUser=$x.username
 }
 $outtbl += $t
 }
 catch [Exception]
 {
     "Error communicating with $computer, skipping to next"   
 }
$outtbl | select Computername,enabled,description,ipAddress,Ou,Type,Serialnumber,Manufacturer,Model,Ram,ProcessorName,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors,Addresswidth,Operatingsystem,loggedinuser,Lastlogondate |export-csv -Append C:\temp\VerynewAdinventory.csv -nti
}
}
```

Comment: "when i import" - which options did you select in Excel while importing the CSV?

Comment: I try two thing with this issue, one of these is creating the file with my script and the other its in excel >Data text to columns > Delimited >Tab, coma and dot and nothing happens.

Comment: Just looking at the image from Excel, Apparently, your locale's `ListSeparator` is different from the comma `Export-Csv` uses by default as delimiter character. Append switch `-UseCulture` to the cmdlet to have PowerShell use the field delimiter character your Excel understands when double-clicking the output.csv file.

Comment: @Theo Its works !! but with the -UseCulture the export looks good but take like 5 or 7 less devicesnow takes the one called ERP i dont know why

Comment: Ok i dont know why but the script only export in excel the last device he check, shoud i use another parameter or use -append to print all in my excel?

Comment: That's some of the most horrid indentation I've ever seen. Do yourself the favour of formatting the code properly, it will help understand your own code better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, your locale computer uses a different delimiter character that `Export-Csv` by default uses (that is the comma).
You can check what character your computer (and thus your Excel) uses like this:

```
[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator
```

To use Export-Csv in a way that you can simply double-click the output csv file to open in Excel, you need to either append switch `-UseCulture` to it, **OR** tell it what the delimiter should be if not a comma by appending parameter `-Delimiter` followed by the character you got from the above code line.

That said, your code does not produce the full table, because the export to the csv file is in the wrong place. As [Palle Due](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68496564/powershell-export-csv-looks-weird?noredirect=1#comment121056145_68496564) commented, you could have seen that if you would **indent** your code properly.

Also, I would advise to use more self-describing variable names, so not `$r` or `$x`, but `$memory` and `$machine` for instance.

Nowadays, you should use `Get-CimInstance` rather than `Get-WmiObject`
AND adding to an array with `+=` should be avoided as it is both time and memory consuming. (on every addition to an array, which is of fixed size, the **entire** array has to be rebuilt in memory).

Your code revised:

```
# set the $ErrorActionPreference to Stop, so you don't have to add -ErrorAction Stop everywhere in the script
# remember the currens value, so you can restore that afterwards.
$oldErrorPref = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# get an array of computers, gathering all properties you need
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter "OperatingSystem -like '*Server*'" -Properties OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate, IPv4Address, Description
$result = foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $serverName = $computer.Name
    if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Quiet)) {
        Write-Host "cannot reach $serverName offline" -ForegroundColor Red
        continue  # skip this computer and proceed with the next one
    }

    try {
        # instead of Get-WmiObject, nowadays you should use Get-CimInstance
        $bios      = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_bios -ComputerName $serverName
        $processor = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor -ComputerName $serverName 
        $memory    = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $serverName
        $disks     = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $serverName
        $machine   = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $serverName | 
                     Select-Object @{Name = "Type"; Expression = {
                                        if ($_.pcsystemtype -eq '2') {'Laptop'} else {'Desktop Or Other something else'}}
                                   },
                                   Manufacturer,
                                   @{Name = "Model"; Expression = {
                                        if (!$_.model) {'Virtual'} else {$_.model}}
                                   },
                                   UserName
        # output an object to be collected in variable $result
        # put the properties in the order you would like in the output
        [PsCustomObject] @{
            ComputerName              = $serverName
            Enabled                   = $computer.Enabled
            Description               = $computer.description
            IpAddress                 = $computer.IPv4Address
            Ou                        = $computer.DistinguishedName.split(',')[1].split('=')[1]
            Type                      = $machine.type
            SerialNumber              = $bios.serialnumber
            Manufacturer              = $machine.Manufacturer
            Model                     = $machine.Model
            Ram                       = '{0} GB' -f (($memory | Measure-Object Capacity -Sum).Sum / 1GB)
            ProcessorName             = $processor.Name
            NumberOfCores             = $processor.NumberOfCores
            NumberOfLogicalProcessors = $processor.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
            Addresswidth              = $processor.Addresswidth
            OperatingSystem           = $computer.OperatingSystem
            # {0:N2} returns the number formatted with two decimals 
            TotalFreeDiskSpace        = '{0:N2} GB' -f (($disks | Measure-Object FreeSpace -Sum).Sum / 1GB)
            LoggedInUser              = $machine.UserName
            Lastlogondate             = $computer.LastLogonDate
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Error communicating with computer $serverName, skipping to next"   
    }
}
# restore the ErrorActionPreference to its former value
$ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorPref

# output the completed array in a CSV file 
# (using the delimiter characer your local machine has set as ListSeparator)
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\VerynewAdinventory.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for help but i have a last question about add more fields of information in a future, now im trying to get the AD computers with "C" Freespace but when i use  `$hdd       = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Computername $serverName` in the csv file returns me System object, in `CustomObject` i add the formula to calc in GB but it doesnt work. If i run the command alone Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Computername $RandomAdname` it works without GB but it works.

Comment: @andresgonz21 That's because a computer may have (and probably **has**) more than one logical disk. If you want to get the freespace combined for all of these disks, please see my edit where I have put that in.